# easy_install extra build arguments

Tags: python, easy-install

I'm trying to install [ReportLab](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/), but I have no C compiler available to compile the rl_accel library. Using setup.py, I would add an extra argument like so:

```
python setup.py --rl_accel=no install
```

Is it possible to add extra arguments to easy_install so that I can reproduce the same effect?

```
easy_install reportlab [something here?]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not using the command, but you can write the configuration file:

http://packages.python.org/distribute/easy_install.html#controlling-build-options

Comment: Thanks! In this case, "no you can't do that" is a good answer.